# Validate custom HTTP header in PHP which sent by iOS

Tags: php, ios, http-headers, localhost, nsmutableurlrequest

What I'm trying to do is, sending a HTTP request with custom header from my iOS application to my localhost which runs XAMPP in my MAC machine. Then there is a PHP page which check my particular header and respond according to that.

Following is the iOS part

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://127.0.0.1/restapi/index.php?name=anuja";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request addValue:@"apiuser" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-USERNAME"];

NSLog(@"%s - %d # allHTTPHeaderFields = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%s - %d # responseStr = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, responseStr);
```

And following is the way I'm checking that particular header from my PHP script

```
        if (isset($_GET["name"])) {

            foreach (headers_list() as $name => $value) {

                if (strcmp($value, "X-USERNAME: apiuser") == 0) {

                    $name = $_GET["name"];

                    $result = json_encode(array('name' => $name), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

                    sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));

                    return true;
                }
            }

            sendResponse(203, 'Non-Authoritative Information');
            return false;
        }
```

I'm always getting "Non-Authoritative Information" as response. But I need to get the response with my name which is in 200 status code.

As far as I can understand the problem is with the way I checked the HTTP header inside my PHP script

```
if (strcmp($value, "X-USERNAME: apiuser") == 0)
```

May be that is not the standard way to check header values and compare it with a pre defined string value in PHP. Is there any way to print the HTTP request header which it receives from PHP side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`headers_list()` returns an array of *response* headers that were already sent or are ready to be sent.

To inspect *request* headers, use [`getallheaders()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php). It returns an associative array of header name and value pairs, so to check if `X-USERNAME` header is present and its value is `apiuser`, you'd do something like:

```
$request_headers = getallheaders();
if(isset($request_headers['X-USERNAME']) && $request_headers['X-USERNAME'] == 'apiuser') {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this functions getallheaders() ,apache_request_headers() ,http_get_request_headers()